# Bidding Theory and Probability of getting highest value in list after ignoring first half of list

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, auction-theory

You are offering an item for sale and there are n bidders. The bidders appear in
sequence. When bidder i appears he or she makes a bid bi > 0. You must decide immediately
whether to accept the bid or not. If you accept the bid, the item is sold to the bidder and all other
bidders are turned away. If you reject the bid, the bidder departs and the bid is withdrawn.
You decide to use the following strategy. You watch the first n/2 bids without accepting any of
them. Let b∗ be the highest bid among these. Then, in the final n/2 bids, you accept any bid that
is larger than b∗. (If there is no such bid, you accept the final bid).
What is the probability that you’ll get the highest bid? Find the answer in terms of n. If n = 50,
what is this value?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8Z6u.png)

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: There is not enough information to answer the question, since you have not specified the random distributions of the bids.

Comment: @MikeEarnest - so long the bids appear in random order with zero probability of ties, the unknown distribution does not matter.  This is a version of the secretary problem (and not the optimal strategy)

Comment: @Henry But OP never specified the bids came in in a random order. The point is, they need to describe the problem completely and clearly.